# Is there any way to test the water pressure at a structure, and if necessary from a specific output (hose bib)?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, hose, irrigation, testing

Reading about irrigation sprinklers ([example product](https://www.hunterindustries.com/irrigation-product/rotors/pgj)), I see a certain recommended PSI. With interest in powering an existing irrigation zone from the hose bib attached to the property, it seems prudent to know the PSI available at the hose bib. How can I test this? Is there a DIY option, or an inexpensive tool? (If possible, it would be nice if this tool could be reusable for other applications too, as most of us DIY folk would likely be more amenable to purchasing a tool if it were reusable for other procedures.)

Comment: Is there a hill or tall tree nearby? Got enough hose to gain 60-80' of altitude?

Comment: @harper Hose? Yes. Ladder? No... Besides, I'd need a hose with a cross section of one inch square, and that's a big hose...

Comment: No, for this test, any diameter of hose will do.  You aren't under the impression that height or distance **requires** large diameter, are you?  Actually that works like resistance, PSI reduction is proportionate to flow.  So for instance if you have 10 irrigation zones and a small pipe, that may work.  Just run 1, then 2, then 3.  If you want to fire them all at once, then that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Harper This is to use only one zone at a time, but yes, gaining appropriate height is likely prohibitive. Although, I'm wondering if the output PSI is less than 25, so perhaps a 25' rise would be sufficient?

Comment: PSI vs height is easy.  It is 1 PSI per 2 feet of altitude.  So if your head is 25' above your outlet, you'll lose 12.5 PSI.  If the head is 25' below, you'll gain 12.5 PSI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want a water pressure gauge with a female hose thread. There are some on Amazon for less than US$10.

Comment: Bought and on the way. Bonus points because it was on sale.